# Calculus with rings. Kinda simple but I don't get it..

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> If $(A, +, •)$ is a ring and $(x^2+x+1)y = y(x^2+x+1)$, $\forall x, y \in A$ then $A$ is commutative.

Book answer:
We put $x \to - x$ and we have $2(xy-yx)=0$ then $xy=yx$. How do I know $2$ is not divisor of $0$?

> If $(A, +, •)$ a ring with unity such that $x^3=x^2, \forall x \in A$. Show that $x^2 = x$ and $A$ is commutative.

Book answer:
We put $x \to 1$ and we have $1=-1$ and $x+x=0$. After we put $x \to x+1$ we have $3x^2 + 3x = 0$ then $x^2 = x$.
How do I know $3$ is not divisor of $0$?

Comment: For the second problem, $3=(1+1)+1=0+1=1$.

Comment: Thank you. What about first problem? :)

Comment: For the first problem, I suspect that the book forgot to mention an assumption that should have been included with the problem statement.

Comment: What book are you using? Maybe this is a known problem and some errata are published.

Comment: It's a Romanian book, Mircea Ganga class 12.

Comment: No, the statement of the first problem is correct (even if the proof isn’t fixable). Use the fact that $y$ and $(x+y)^2+(x+y)$ commute, as well as $y$ and $x^2+x$, to deduce that $y$ commutes with $x^2$, which concludes.

Comment: That’s almost literally the hypothesis: $y$ must commute with any $z^2+z+1$, $z \in A$, so it must commute with any $z^2+z$, in particular with any $(x+y)^2+(x+y)$.

Comment: I got IT! Thank you both, love you guys!